# How to parse JSON Array (Not Json Object) in Android

Tags: java, android, json, gson, arrays

I have a trouble finding a way how to parse JSONArray.
It looks like this:

```
[{"name":"name1","url":"url1"},{"name":"name2","url":"url2"},...]
```

I  know how to parse it if the JSON was written differently (In other words, if I had json object returned instead of an array of objects). 
But it's all I have and have to go with it.

*EDIT: It is a valid json. I made an iPhone app using this json, now I need to do it for Android and cannot figure it out.
There are a lot of examples out there, but they are all JSONObject related. I need something for JSONArray.

Can somebody please give me some hint, or a tutorial or an example?

Much appreciated !

Comment: Try this to see if your json is valid http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: are you using any library for parsing json? Use gson library for json parsing.Much Helpfull.

Comment: It is valid. I parsed it in an app i did for an iPhone And it's working. I just dont know how to do it in Android

Comment: @nikash, yeah i noticed i could use gson. only problem is, all examples i found are for parsing a JSONObject not JSONArray

Comment: Post your code that you have tried so far.It will be helpful to give a precise answer accordingly.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

use the following snippet to parse the JsonArray.

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = jsonobject.getString("name");
    String url = jsonobject.getString("url");
}
```

Comment: just one question if jsonarray includes numerics like [2].[4] and that numerics inside includes again an array so if i want to retrieve from especially lets say the array nested in numeric [4] in java code i must write int i=4???

Comment: @BiggDawgg: Glad it helped you. Post your question in a separate thread with  JSON data so that it would be easy for me to answer.

Answer (score 27):

I'll just give a little [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) example:

First create a data holder which has the fields from JSON string

```
// imports
// ...
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyDataHolder {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String mName;

    @JsonProperty("url")
    public String mUrl;
}
```

And parse list of MyDataHolders

```
String jsonString = // your json
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<MyDataHolder> list = mapper.readValue(jsonString, 
    new TypeReference<ArrayList<MyDataHolder>>() {});
```

Using list items

```
String firstName = list.get(0).mName;
String secondName = list.get(1).mName;
```

Comment: Can you give me an example how would i get JSON as a string from url i have, please ?

Comment: The `DefaultHttpClient`s execute-method is a blocking call so it has to be done in a background task, just to make clear why it is in separate class.

Comment: Im being given an error about the constructor of HttpGetTask.
"The constructor HttpGetTask(OnHttpGetCompletedListener) refers to the missing type OnHttpGetCompletedListener"

Comment: have you imported OnHttpGetCompletedListener? Like this `import your_package_name_here.HttpGetTask.OnHttpGetCompletedListener;`

Comment: Yeap, that was the problem...
Thanks for solving my issue :)

Answer (score 22):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
    String str = "[{\"name\":\"name1\",\"url\":\"url1\"},{\"name\":\"name2\",\"url\":\"url2\"}]";

    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(str);


    for(int i=0; i<jsonarray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

        String name = obj.getString("name");
        String url = obj.getString("url");

        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(url);
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
name1
url1
name2
url2
```

Answer (score 12):

Create a class to hold the objects.

```
public class Person{
   private String name;
   private String url;
   //Get & Set methods for each field
}
```

Then deserialize as follows:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Person[] person = gson.fromJson(input, Person[].class); //input is your String
```

**Reference Article:** http://blog.patrickbaumann.com/2011/11/gson-array-deserialization/

Comment: I asume this "input" would be URL to that json?
or is it something else?

Comment: This is a very simple solution. It should be the accepted one in my view

Answer (score 6):

```
public class CustomerInfo 
{   
    @SerializedName("customerid")
    public String customerid;
    @SerializedName("picture")
    public String picture;

    @SerializedName("location")
    public String location;

    public CustomerInfo()
    {}
}
```

And when you get the result; parse like this

```
List<CustomerInfo> customers = null;
customers = (List<CustomerInfo>)gson.fromJson(result, new TypeToken<List<CustomerInfo>>() {}.getType());
```

Comment: Result variable is your JSONArray String

Comment: Would result variable  be the url i need to fetch json from or already fetched json ?

Comment: by far the easiest solution

Answer (score 6):

In this example there are several objects inside one json array. That is,

This is the json array: [{"name":"name1","url":"url1"},{"name":"name2","url":"url2"},...]

This is one object: {"name":"name1","url":"url1"}

Assuming that you have got the result to a String variable called jSonResultString:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(jSonResultString);

  //loop through each object
  for (int i=0; i<arr.length(); i++){

  JSONObject jsonProductObject = arr.getJSONObject(i);
  String name = jsonProductObject.getString("name");
  String url = jsonProductObject.getString("url");


}
```

Comment: Im having a hard time getting my JSONstring from URL.
Maybe you could help with that?

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down with examples, good clarity

Answer (score 3):

A few great suggestions are already mentioned.
Using GSON is really handy indeed, and to make life even easier you can try this [website](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)
It's called jsonschema2pojo and does exactly that:

You give it your json and it generates a java object that can paste in your project.
You can select GSON to annotate your variables, so extracting the object from your json gets even easier!

Answer (score 2):

My case
Load From Server Example..

```
int jsonLength = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("number_of_messages"));
            if (jsonLength != 1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonLength; i++) {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("messages"));
                    JSONObject resJson = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                    //addItem(resJson.getString("message"), resJson.getString("name"), resJson.getString("created_at"));
                }
```

Comment: p.s "jsonObject.getString("messages")" type is jsonArray;

first exist answer is cannot be convert string to jsonArray;
i'm fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Create a POJO Java Class for the objects in the list like so:

```
class NameUrlClass{
       private String name;
       private String url;
       //Constructor
       public NameUrlClass(String name,String url){
              this.name = name;
              this.url = url; 
        }
}
```

Now simply create a List of NameUrlClass and initialize it to an ArrayList like so:

```
List<NameUrlClass> obj = new ArrayList<NameUrlClass>;
```

You can use store the JSON array in this object

```
obj = JSONArray;//[{"name":"name1","url":"url1"}{"name":"name2","url":"url2"},...]
```

Comment: It's not clear what `obj = JSONArray;` is supposed to do. What is `JSONArray` in this context? Where does it come from? What is the purpose of initializing `obj` with a `new ArrayList<NameUrlClass>`, when you replace it directly afterwards anyways?

Answer (score -3):

Old post I know, but unless I've misunderstood the question, this should do the trick:

```
s = '[{"name":"name1","url":"url1"},{"name":"name2","url":"url2"}]';
eval("array=" + s);
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
for (var index in array[i]) {
    alert(array[i][index]);
}
```

}

Answer (score -3):

```
            URL url = new URL("your URL");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader;
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            //setting the json string
            String finalJson = buffer.toString();

            //this is your string get the pattern from buffer.
            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(finalJson);
```