# Parsing JSON response without an array name

Tags: android, json

```
[
  {

    "stDescription": "END N/A",
    "stCategory": "6",
    "sZone": "@",
    "sIncident": "0"
  },
  {

    "stDescription": "BEG N/A",
    "stCategory": "6",
    "sZone": "@",
    "sIncident": "0"
  },
  {

    "stDescription": "",
    "stCategory": "Null",
    "sZone": "4",
    "sIncident": "0"
  },
  {

    "stDescription": "",
    "stCategory": "Null",
    "sZone": "5",
    "sIncident": "0"
  }
]
```

There is no array name here, but I want to parse whole array (my JSON parser works fine if I'm using array name).

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: Parsing this JSON is not possible by developers :D ..please provide more information

Comment: Please search first I think this is old question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977144/how-to-parse-json-array-not-json-object-in-android

Comment: For parsing this array, you don't need any `name` of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For parsing this type of `JSON`...

First store it in `String`..

and then do following process...

```
String str = "JSON STRING";
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(str);

for(int i=0; i<jsonarray.length(); i++){
    JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

    String stDescription = obj.getString("stDescription");
    String stCategory= obj.getString("stCategory");
    //and other fields

    System.out.println(stDescription);
    System.out.println(stCategory);
}
```

This may help you...