# Iterate Array of JSON objects

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am using `org.json.simple` library to construct `JSONArray` of `JSONObject`. So my structure looks like

```
c= [
  {
    "name":"test",
    "age":1
  },
  {
   "name":"test",
   "age":1
   }
]
```

To iterate the array in java, I tried

```
for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) c.get(i);
    System.out.println(obj.get("name"));        
}
```

It printed `null`, but when tried to print the `obj.toString`, it prints the JSON string as expected.

I am using `org.json.simple` jar, so cannot use the methods defined `org.json.JSONArray` or `org.json.JSONObject`.

Any ideas to get the values from the object with their key?

Comment: What is `i< c=arr.size()`? Which type `c` has?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977144/how-to-parse-json-array-not-json-object-in-android

Comment: `c = arr.size()` and then `c.get(i)` ? That shouldn't compile. So please post the exact code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @AlexisC, sorry its a typo , updated the code now

Comment: @TagirValeev Its `c.size()` , please have a look at my update

Comment: @SanKrish Works for me: http://pastebin.com/bJbQ2avY It prints "test" two times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the `JSONArray` elements using an `Iterator`, like this:

```
    //arr is your JSONArray here
    Iterator<Object> iterator = arr.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Object obj = iterator.next();
        if(obj instanceof JSONObject) {
             System.out.println(obj.get("name"));
        }
    }
```

It uses `org.json.simple.JSONObject` and `org.json.simple.JSONArray`.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is absolutely correct, it works fine with `org.json.simple`:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class JsonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        JSONArray c = (JSONArray) new JSONParser()
                .parse("[ { \"name\":\"test\", \"age\":1 }, "
                        + "{ \"name\":\"test\", \"age\":1 } ]");
        for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) c.get(i);
            System.out.println(obj.get("name"));        
        }
    }
}
```

It outputs:

```
test
test
```

Check how input `JSONArray` was created. It's possible that there's something different inside it. For example, it's possible that you have non-printable character in key name, so you don't see it when using `c.toString()`, but `obj.get("name")` fails.

Answer (score 1):

use the following snippet to parse the JsonArray.

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = jsonobject.getString("name");
    int age = jsonobject.getInt("age");
}
```

Hope it helps.

Credits - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18977257/3036759

Comment: no this will not work as mentioned in the question , am using `org.simple.json` JSONArray. it doesnt have `length()` method