# How to read one json object

Tags: java, json

I want to read a json object in one go.The code I have written is reading json but not in same order.

My data in json is:

```
 {
    "protocolDate":"2014-09-08",
    "spName":"UL",
    "testId":"123",
    "productDescription":"Refrigerator-Freezer",
    "protocolType":"Test Protocol Template",
    "sampleSize":"1",
    "protocolName":"Refrigerator-Freezer"}
```

My code is:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("./NewTestImport.json"));

JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
String protocolDate = (String) jsonObject.get("protocolDate");      
String spName = (String) jsonObject.get("spName");
String testId = (String) jsonObject.get("testId");
String productDescription = (String) jsonObject.get("productDescription");
String protocolType = (String) jsonObject.get("protocolType");
String sampleSize = (String) jsonObject.get("sampleSize");      
String protocolName = (String) jsonObject.get("protocolName");
List<Map<String,String>> data= new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
data.add(jsonObject);
```

I dont want to initialize each json object explicitly.

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Comment: Not working for me..

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear (at least for me). You are having one JSON object, but you want to parse it as it was a list/array (which it isn't). Please clarify your problem. For now I am *guessing* that you want to create single `Map<String,String> map = ...` where `...` is some simple code which parses your JSON into that map. Then (for whatever reason) add this map to list (but list with only one element is usually code smell which makes your question look like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: Sorry my bad!! I want to parse json file in same order as it is.I am not getting json in same order.

Comment: JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("./NewTestImport.json"));

JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

Comment: Sytem.out.println(jsonObject);  when i am printing this I am getting productDescription  first then testid.but i want to print It in same order.@Pshemo

Comment: If you are using `JSONObject` from `org.json.simple` package, then you need to be aware that `class JSONObject extends HashMap` and `HashMap` doesn't guarantee any order. Maybe try using `com.google.gson` library. With this you can write `JsonElement jElement = new JsonParser().parse(new FileReader("./NewTestImport.json"));`. Now when you will print `jElement` you will get all key:values in original order.

Comment: You could also create your own POJO class which will represent your JSON structure. This would allow you to use `new Gson()` object and its `fromJson(new FileReader("D:\\file.json"), YourClass.class)` to get instance of `YourClass` which will be initialized with values from JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I just modified your code,

```
        Map<String,String>jso = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();             
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("./NewTestImport.json"));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;  
        jso.put("protocolDate", (String) jsonObject.get("protocolDate"));
        jso.put("spName", (String) jsonObject.get("spName"));
        jso.put("testId", (String) jsonObject.get("testId"));
        jso.put("productDescription", (String) jsonObject.get("productDescription"));
        jso.put("protocolType", (String) jsonObject.get("protocolType"));
        jso.put("sampleSize", (String) jsonObject.get("sampleSize"));
        jso.put("protocolName", (String) jsonObject.get("protocolName"));      

        List<Map<String,String>> data= new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
        data.add(jso);   

        System.out.println(data);
```

Output:

```
[{protocolDate=2014-09-08, spName=UL, testId=123, productDescription=Refrigerator-Freezer, protocolType=Test Protocol Template, sampleSize=1, protocolName=Refrigerator-Freezer}]
```

- I used linked hash map so it will store the values in order.
- I hope this is the output you are looking for.
- In case of any clarifications please leave a comment below.

Comment: yea it helped me.But If i want to put Long values then.

Comment: These all are string values @Karthi

Comment: In json everything is consider as string. What do you mean my long values and where need to put this?

Comment: I got one variable Version in json which is taking long values. @Karthi

Comment: "_version_":1530038128825335811},It is like this in json.@Karthi

Comment: It is also consider as string so it can accept this value too.Just add version to your json and try running the program.

Comment: One more thing if my data is like   {    "protocolDate":"2014-09-08", "spName":"UL", "testId":"123","productDescription":"Refrigerator-Freezer", "protocolType":"Test Protocol Template","sampleSize":"1",    "protocolName":"Refrigerator-Freezer"},  { "protocolDate":"2014-10-08",    "spName":"UL","testId":"27995377760e059145100325efc7b4fc_131497bc-ecbf-4abc-995f-bbf482828ba1-1", "productDescription":"Refrigerator-Freezer",
    "protocolType":"Test Protocol Template",
    "sampleSize":"1",
    "protocolName":"Refrigerator-Freezer"}  then this method will not working Getting error in parsing

Comment: This is array of object I guess

Comment: Is this array of objects or something else i have to take.

Comment: Hey i don't get any error, both json's produce the required output.

Comment: If you gave both jsons at same time its an error because its not consider as a valid json.

Comment: Both data are in same json,means i have {  },{  },{  } many documents like dis in json.can i do it with same code.@karthi

Comment: You can't create a valid json by simply using commas(,).Please use jsonlint.com to validate your json

Comment: @Karthi, plz dont mention that JSON support only String it support other datatypes as well, plz go thru the link to understand the datatype accepted in JSON. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_data_types.htm

Comment: If i want to read doc like this [ {..},{ ..},{..} ] how can i read it.

Comment: Hey there are many tutorials to do that, you can also refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977144/how-to-parse-json-array-not-json-object-in-android

Comment: @Karthi One problem i am facing is My file is like {
    "protocolDate":"2014-10-08",
    "spName":"UL",
    "testId":"2799",},                                                                                              { "protocolDate":"2014-10-08",
    "spName":"UL",
    "testId":"2799",} means not in one line  "protocolDate":"2014-10-08","spName":"UL","testId":"2799} so this code is not working

Comment: Hey I can give you a simple solution, in the json file write every jsons line by line without comma at the end
Then using buffer reader read the json file line by line.
For each line do parsing using a while loop.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Gson here is a good link [gson api](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)

Here you can see simple example

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
// 1. JSON to Java object, read it from a file.
Staff staff = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("D:\\file.json"), Staff.class);
// 2. JSON to Java object, read it from a Json String.
String jsonInString = "{'name' : 'mkyong'}";
Staff staff = gson.fromJson(jsonInString, Staff.class);
// JSON to JsonElement, convert to String later.
JsonElement json = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("D:\\file.json"), JsonElement.class);
String result = gson.toJson(json);
```

Comment: While content from link may answer OP question, this answer may become useless for future readers if link will brake (which happens quite often). It is better to post main solution in answer itself, and leave link as source of *additional* info. More info at: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: I dont want to write it anywhere.I just want to store it in array because i need to upload it to something in one go.