# JSON PARSING ARRAY

Tags: php, android, json

How can I parse this JSON array in android?

[Photograph of JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuZt2.png)

This is my android code:

```
private Boolean parseData(){
    try{

        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(jsonData);
        JSONObject jo = null;

        wantedLists.clear();
        WantedList wantedList;

        for(int i = 0; i<ja.length(); i++){

            jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            String lastname=jo.getString("lastname");
            String alyas=jo.getString("alyas");
            String reward=jo.getString("reward");
            String authority=jo.getString("authority");
            String location_name=jo.getString("location_name");
            String firstname=jo.getString( "firstname" );
            String middlename=jo.getString( "middlename" );
            String imageUrl=jo.getString("url");
            wantedList = new WantedList();

            wantedList.setLastname(lastname);
            wantedList.setAlyas(alyas);
            wantedList.setAuthority(authority);
            wantedList.setReward(reward);
            wantedList.setLocation_name(location_name);
            wantedList.setFirstname( firstname );
            wantedList.setMiddlename( middlename );
            wantedList.setImageUrl(imageUrl);

           wantedLists.add(wantedList);
        }
    }
```

Using the above code, the array is not parsed, can someone spot the bug?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977144/how-to-parse-json-array-not-json-object-in-android

Comment: What is your expected result? Normally in PHP you would just use json decode it if you need to access individual values. i.e. `json_decode($string, true)`

Comment: sorry Iam really new in this page i dont know how to post the problem i just want to parse the json data so i cant view it on my android application. how can i parse it?

Comment: are you getting any error on using above code??

Comment: i dont get any error but i just cant get the data to android studio when i run my program the response is unable to parse data

Comment: try logging and reading the error inside the `catch(Exception e)` block (which you should also include in the posted code), there's probably some info there on why the JSON can't be parsed

Comment: Iam really sorry I just started to post in this page just this day so i dont know what to do here thank you for informing me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON uses middlename with an uppercase 'M':

```
"Middlename": "Lumbres",
```

But your JSON parser uses middlename with a lowercase 'm':

```
String middlename=jo.getString( "middlename" );
```

That should throw a `org.json.JSONException: No value for middlename` error.

Either modify your app's JSON parser to get "Middlename" or modify the JSON response (if you control the server or module that spits out the response) to use "middlename".

Comment: thanks i didnt see that ,  do i need to make the same name in php and android?

Comment: yes, the json keys in your parser and the response should match

Comment: thankyou so much for that information it really helps a lot

Comment: @JzonCharles what other errors did you get with the json parsing?