# PHP json parsing. Don't set Duplicate

Tags: php, arrays, json, parsing

Guys its **not duplicate** please cause my `json` start with:

```
[
 {

 }
]
```

without root element. I don't know how to parse this as your answers. I'm new to php. currently developing a android app that send a json string to php.. My json data is in format of string.
How can I parse this string in php. I need every  `id` and `name` from this string to store in database...

```
[
 {"name":"Abhishek Singh",
  "photo":"http:\........./diary\/photos\/student\/26.png",
  "rollno":"1",
  "id":"26"},
 {"name":"Ashutosh Tripathi",
  "photo":"http:\........./diary\/photos\/student\/34.png",
  "rollno":"2",
  "id":"34"},
 {"name":"Ayushi Srivastava",
  "photo":"http:\............./diary\/photos\/student\/42.png",
  "rollno":"3",
  "id":"42"
 }
]
```

Comment: try to use json_decode you can see it's details at http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: bro I am android developer so i don't know how to get that data in $var.. just little help needed how to get id from that

Comment: @AbhishekSingh: Post it with PHP tags will get better response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON Array (Not Json Object) in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977144/how-to-parse-json-array-not-json-object-in-android)

Comment: I think this is a valid question. I remember years back when I started working with json and I only had a little over a year's experience in php, working with json can get super confusing ... I say leave the question here... okay you guys hav valid points....

Comment: @VishalChhodwani i did'nt ask for parsing in android.. i don't know why downvoting

Comment: There is my +1 on the question even after flagging it the duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your photo value is not correct it's value should be like

```
"photo":"http://........./diary\/photos\/student\/26.png"
```

or

```
"photo":"http:/diary\/photos\/student\/26.png"
```

or some thing else not like `http:\....`

And if it's value is fixed then it's solution is

```
$json = '[{"name":"Abhishek Singh",
  "photo":"http://........./diary\/photos\/student\/26.png",
  "rollno":"1",
  "id":"26"},
 {"name":"Ashutosh Tripathi",
  "photo":"http://........./diary\/photos\/student\/34.png",
  "rollno":"2",
  "id":"34"},
 {"name":"Ayushi Srivastava",
  "photo":"http://............./diary\/photos\/student\/42.png",
  "rollno":"3",
  "id":"42"}]';

$obj = json_decode($json);
foreach ($obj as $key=>$record){
    echo $record->id;
}
```

Comment: its in correct form I added dots there cause of not sharing link

Comment: Then i hope this answer will solve your problem. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$data = json_decode($json,true);//$json is your json data

foreach($data as $key=>$value){
print_r($value);// this should print each array of json
}
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c4a7ed6fd23b3efe8356eb04e05238b3a9b2e03c)

Answer (score 1):

To parse

```
try {

   JSONArray jr = new JSONArray("string_name");
   JSONObject jb = (JSONObject)jr.getJSONObject(0);
   JSONArray st = jb.getJSONArray("key");
   for(int i=0;i<st.length();i++)
       {
      String id= st.getString(i);
      String name= st.getString(i+1);
      Log.i("..........",""+key);
      // loop and add it to array or arraylist
        }
   }catch(Exception e)
   {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Once you parse and add it to array. Use the same to populate your spinner.

`[` represents json array node

`{` represents json object node

Comment: I have to parse in php not in android... I'm posting that json to php..

Comment: @Deo read the question carefully. i am sending this json from android

Comment: @AbhishekSingh still no need to add tag `android` everyone here is thinking that u want to parse json in android ... **beware from the next time.. soon ur question will be closed** .

Comment: @AbhishekSingh check my [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41562121/1761003).. If anything helps it try to **upvote** .. That is how [stackoverflow works](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @MaňishYadav nice answer I think :-)

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over a multidimensional array, you can use `RecursiveArrayIterator`

```
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        echo "$key:\n";
    } else {
        echo "$key => $val\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
John:
status => Not Active
Jennifer:
status => Active
James:
status => Active
age => 52
count => 14
progress => 29857
bad => 10
```

Comment: @AbhishekSingh keep those things in mind ... and have nice reputation on SO