# Troubles with parsing JSON for android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I'm working on parsing some JSON in my android application, this is the code I started off with:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = **new JSONObject(result);**
int receivedCount = **jsonObject.getInt("CurrentCount");**
```

However this is causing it to error (The code that would error is surrounded with asterisks) in Android Studio, I tried using the suggestion feature which asked me if I want "Surround with try/catch" which would cause the app to crash when it launched.

This is the suggested code:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = null;
try {
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

int receivedCount = 0;
try {
    receivedCount = jsonObject.getInt("CurrentCount");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is the JSON I'm trying to pass:

```
[{"CurrentCount":"5"},{"CurrentCount":"0"},{"CurrentCount":"1002"}]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure... Your JSON isn't JSONObject. This is JSONArray.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON Array (Not Json Object) in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977144/how-to-parse-json-array-not-json-object-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

J_Dadh I think first of all you should look through the documentation on how to use Json Parser which you can find in the following Link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

### EXAMPLE JSON

```
{
   "sys":
   {
      "country":"GB",
      "sunrise":1381107633,
      "sunset":1381149604
   },
   "weather":[
      {
         "id":711,
         "main":"Smoke",
         "description":"smoke",
         "icon":"50n"
      }
   ],

  "main":
   {
      "temp":304.15,
      "pressure":1009,
   }
}


String YourJsonObject = "JsonString" 

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(YourJsonObject);

JSONArray weather = jsonObj.getJSONArray("weather");



for (int i = 0; i < weather.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = weather.getJSONObject(i);
    String id = c.getString("id");
    String main= c.getString("main");
    String description= c.getString("description");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as you pasted your JSON you are using `[{"CurrentCount":"5"},{"CurrentCount":"0"},{"CurrentCount":"1002"}]`

-If we analyze this JSON,This JSON contains a JSON ARRAY `[{"CurrentCount":"5"},{"CurrentCount":"0"},{"CurrentCount":"1002"}]`
having 3 JSON Objects`{"CurrentCount":"5"},{"CurrentCount":"0"},{"CurrentCount":"1002"}`

-But when you are going to parse this JSON, you are accepting it as `jsonObject = new JSONObject(result)`,but you should accept it as`JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(result);`

and then you iterate a loop(e.g,for loop) on this `jsonArray`,accepting JSONObjects 1 by 1,then getting the values from the each JSONObject 1 by 1.

-1 more mistake in your JSON is that you are sending the strings as "5" but accepting it as `getInt()` that's not fair,you should send `int` to accept it as `int`as 5 (without double qoutes)

So you final JSON and code like this(as below)
**JSON**
`[{"CurrentCount":5},{"CurrentCount":0},{"CurrentCount":1002}]`

**Code to Use this JSON**

```
JSONOArray jsonArray = null;
try{
       jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
       for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length;i++){
       JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray[i];
       receivedCount=jsonObject.getInt("CurrentCount");
       }
   }catch(JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```