# Parse json array in Java Object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am invoking API which returns JSON as a response which I am parsing into POJO using Jackson. It is working fine but
failing for below JSON array format,

```
{
...
"data" : [
    {  
        "2017-12-05 21:40:33":"1537"
     },
     {  
        "2017-12-07 23:51:16":"1539"
     },
     {  
        "2017-12-12 22:57:10":"1539"
     }
],
...
}
```

This date in key is generated at time of data captured in server side, my application invoking API which returns above format 
of JSON so can you please let me know how I can parse this JSON in Java POJO.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Jackson to deserialise an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON Array (Not Json Object) in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977144/how-to-parse-json-array-not-json-object-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but mentioned above answers key are fix so I can add it in to POJO as a property but in my case key (which is date) is not fix so every time when I invoke this API I will get different Key in response.

Comment: has to be parsed in Map<String, String>

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to following.

```
public class POJO {
    ...
    List<Map<String,String>> data;
    ...   
}
```

You can also format the key as `java.util.Date` if needed, *registering the date type serializer* in the Jaskson's object mapper builder.