# Set json response get_Infographs value in recycler view of this data

Tags: android, arrays, json

{
    "count": 7,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "get_Infographs": [
                {
                    "viewCount": 17,
                    "likecount": 1,
                    "unlikeCount": 1,
                    "shareCount": 0,
                    "i_id": 532,
                    "p_id": 532,
                    "name": "Yoga  happiness  educational  s",
                    "description": "Yoga  happiness  educational  spiritual  journey  lifestyle  health ",
                    "c_id": 1,
                    "status_id": 1,
                    "source_id": 316,
                    "date_created": null,
                    "parentinfograph": "Language  english  grammar  apo",
                    "internal_url": "http://167.99.86.81:8000/media/DQ532.png",
                    "external_url": "http://yogadork.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/2015-yoga-resolutions-infographic.png",
                    "mt_id": 3,
                    "mtcode": "Education",
                    "topics": [
                        {
                            "topic_code": "#EDUCATION"
                        },
                        {
                            "topic_code": "#HEALTH"
                        }
                    ],
                    "geoPolitical": [
                        {
                            "gp_code": "Default  / All GPIDs"
                        }
                    ],
                    "entity": [],
                    "customMetaTags": [
                        {
                            "metatag": "#"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
]
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON Array (Not Json Object) in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977144/how-to-parse-json-array-not-json-object-in-android)

Comment: which one is a problem? 1) get data from JSON. 2) send data through bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Read `customMetaTags` it as ArrayList and then you can pass it using bundle

```
bundle.putSerializable("some_string", arrayList)
```