# represent Json array of object in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I would like to know if this is a valid Json structure its just an array of objects with no attribute name
I used [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) and it says **Valid JSON**

How to represent the same in java?

```
[
   {
    "printerId": "100",
    "printerStatus": true,
    "error": null
    },
    {
    "printerId": "150",
    "printerStatus": false,
    "error": "no power"
    },
    {
    "printerId": "180",
    "printerStatus": false,
    "error": "Ink Levels Low"
    }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried? How isn't it working?

Comment: [JSON Java Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm)

Comment: There are quite a few links that go into parsing JSONArrays, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977144/how-to-parse-json-array-not-json-object-in-android) and [these](https://www.google.com/#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+parse+json+array).

Comment: declare a class Painter with fields printerId, printerStatus and error. the structure above is just a List of Painter objects.

Comment: Thank you Hovercraft, JSONArray is what I was looking for. totally forgot about this.

Comment: Glad that you've got it working

Comment: Hovercraft do you want to post as answer so I can accept it. the duplicate is related to Android