# How to read all JSON objects from json file? Java

Tags: java, json

When I try to read objects from Json file - it only iteratesthrough one object 4 times.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String file = "src/main/resources/ip.json";
        String json = readFileAsString(file);
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(json);
       
        HashMap result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, HashMap.class);
        
            for (Object entry : result.keySet()) {

                String id = (String) jo.get().get("id");
                System.out.println(id);
                String ip = (String) jo.get("ip");
                System.out.println(ip);
                Integer score = (Integer) jo.get("score");
                System.out.println(score);

            }

        }

        public static String readFileAsString (String file) throws IOException {
            return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file)));
        }

    }
```

------------------------------------Json File--------------------------------

```
{
  "id": "test",
  "score": 12,
  "ip": "1.2.3.4",
  "message": "Hi"
},
{
"id": "test",
"score": 5,
"ip": "1.2.3.5"
},
{
"id": "test",
"score": 17,
"ip": "1.2.3.4"
},
{
"id": "test2",
"score": 9,
"ip": "1.2.3.4"
}
```

---

OUTPUT:

test
1.2.3.4
12
test
1.2.3.4
12
test
1.2.3.4
12
test
1.2.3.4
12

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read MULTIPLE json objects, they should be in a JSON array. For example,

```json
[{"id": "test", "score": 12, "ip": "1.2.3.4", "message": "Hi" }, { "id": "test", "score": 5, "ip": "1.2.3.5" }, { "id": "test", "score": 17, "ip": "1.2.3.4" }, { "id": "test2", "score": 9, "ip": "1.2.3.4" }]
```

Please refer to similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18977220/4006222).

Answer (score 0):

Your Json file does not have a json array, only an objects.  Array is something like this.

```
[
 {
   "id": "test",
   "score": 12,
   "ip": "1.2.3.4",
   "message": "Hi"
 },
 {
  "id": "test",
  "score": 5,
  "ip": "1.2.3.5"
 },
 {
  "id": "test",
  "score": 17,
  "ip": "1.2.3.4"
 },
 {
  "id": "test2",
  "score": 9,
  "ip": "1.2.3.4"
 }
]
```

So edit your Json file like above and try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String file = "src/main/resources/ip.json";
        String json = readFileAsString(file);
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        for(int i=0; i < jsonArr.length();i++){
            JSONObject jo = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);       
            System.out.println(jo.getString("id"));
            System.out.println(jo.getString("ip"));
            System.out.println(jo.getInt("score"));
        }

        public static String readFileAsString (String file) throws IOException {
            return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file)));
        }

    }
```

Comment: JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

I received erroron this line  -   Json array cannot apply to string

Comment: Hello, I edited answer. Please refer that.

Comment: Thank you for your help a lot
but still not working

here screenshots 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kp0-GmpE50IIsssjzjZLNz30OEsk-88Z?usp=sharing