# How do i access an array in openweathermap json using java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, api

[image]

In the JSON -photo, I have highlighted the part I need to access in my code and display it in my app.

I tried using JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("weather[0]"), but that led me literally no where haha

So far i have nothing on the matter. Also here is my code.

```
public void getWeather(View view) {
    String apiKey="40bb658a709ebb7b1c210655e7f5cfe6";
    String city=et.getText().toString();
    String url="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+city+"&appid=40bb658a709ebb7b1c210655e7f5cfe6&units=metric";
    RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject("sys");
                String country = object.getString("country");
                tvcountry.setText(country);

                JSONObject object1= response.getJSONObject("main");
                String temperature=object1.getString("temp");
                tvTemp.setText("Current: " + temperature + " C");

                JSONObject object2 = response.getJSONObject("main");
                String feelsLike = object2.getString("feels_like");
                tvFeels_Like.setText("Feels like: " + feelsLike + " C");

                JSONObject object3 = response.getJSONObject("main");
                String maxtemp = object3.getString("temp_max");
                tvMaxTemp.setText("Max: " + maxtemp + " C");

                JSONObject object4 = response.getJSONObject("main");
                String mintemp = object4.getString("temp_min");
                tvMinTemp.setText("Min: " + mintemp + " C");
                
                JSO



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(SecondPage.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    queue.add(request);
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977144/how-to-parse-json-array-not-json-object-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON parser. I am referring to Genson (see http://genson.io/GettingStarted/#deserialize-generic-types):

```
Genson genson = new Genson();
List<Object> persons = genson.deserialize("[{\"age\":28,\"name\":\"Foo\"}]", List.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can continue with `org.json`, too:

```
    @Test
    void getFirstIndexFromJsonArray() {
        // Given
        String rawJson = "{\n" +
                "  \"coors\": {\n" +
                "    \"long\": -0.7888,\n" +
                "    \"lat\": 51.9000\n" +
                "  },\n" +
                "  \"weather\": [\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "      \"id\": 804,\n" +
                "      \"main\": \"Clouds\",\n" +
                "      \"description\": \"overcast clouds\",\n" +
                "      \"icon\": \"04n\"\n" +
                "    },\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "      \"id\": 1044,\n" +
                "      \"main\": \"Thunder\",\n" +
                "      \"description\": \"Thunderbird\",\n" +
                "      \"icon\": \"1944x\"\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  ]\n" +
                "}";

        // When
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(rawJson);
        JSONArray weather = jsonObject.getJSONArray("weather");
        JSONObject firstWeatherEntry = new JSONObject(weather.get(0).toString());

        // Then
        assertThat(firstWeatherEntry.get("description"), is("overcast clouds"));
    }
```